# Is it OK to reheat my spaghetti sauce over & over?

Tags: sauce, reheating

My spaghetti sauce is made with fresh tomatoes, ketchup, garlic, some vinegar, and some basic seasoning. I've been told it's not good to reheat the sauce over & over, but I'm making this for myself, 4 servings at a time, so the most reheats 1 batch would get is 3, and each batch lasts at most 2 days. I've been told to put the sauce in separate containers & only reheat 1 serving when ready to eat. I find it a pain to dirty extra containers and have had no problem reheating my sauce.

Is there some real problem with reheating my spaghetti sauce over & over, or is my family just too careful/concerned about it?

Comment: If you have no problem with reheating over it should be OK (except safety zones consideration) Unfortunately is not very easy to cook decently without some dirty cookware as a collateral damage.

Answer (score 6):

Food safety wise, you want to minimise the amount of time the uneaten sauce spends in the "danger zone", 4-60 degrees Celsius. When you repeatedly reheat and chill food, every time it chills it spends some time (depending on how you chill it and the container you store it in, but usually at least an hour) in the danger zone adding to the risk you will get sick from eating it. A typical recommendation is that food should not spend more than 2 cumulative hours in the danger zone to be considered safe to eat. Why not just scoop out the amount you need for the day onto the plate you will eat from and reheat that? Or, if you're adding it to freshly cooked pasta, dump it directly on the pasta from the fridge and let it stand on a warm burner with the lid on for a few minutes to warm up?